# Is there a better way to select multiple rows in Entity Framework?

Tags: c#, linq, generics, collections

I'm just wondering, is there a better way to fetch data from multiple rows than creating a list of lists, as per the code below?

This isn't really a problem, more of a code smell as one could have 50+ rows and this solution would be impractical in that situation.

Any and all help would be appreciated =]

```cs
class Manage
{
    List<string> UserNames = new List<string>();
    List<string> Lockoutenabled = new List<string>();
    List<string> AccessFailedCount = new List<string>();

    List<List<string>> Details = new List<List<string>>();

    VatsWebEntitiesManage ManageEntity = new VatsWebEntitiesManage();

    public List<List<string>> FetchUserDetails()
    {
        var usernames = ManageEntity.AspNetUsers.Select(m => m.UserName);
        var lockouts = ManageEntity.AspNetUsers.Select(l => l.LockoutEnabled);
        var AccessFailedCounts = ManageEntity.AspNetUsers.Select(afc => afc.AccessFailedCount);

        foreach (var item in usernames)
        {
            UserNames.Add(item);
        }
        foreach (var item in lockouts)
        {
            Lockoutenabled.Add(item.ToString());
        }
        foreach (var item in AccessFailedCounts)
        {
            AccessFailedCount.Add(item.ToString());
        }

        Details.Add(UserNames);
        Details.Add(Lockoutenabled);
        Details.Add(AccessFailedCount);

        return (Details);
    }
}
```

Comment: What is your goal to return? Can't you just define a UserDetail class and create an IEnumerable of them?

Comment: I want to be able to return all rows, but I only need one set of rows I.E `var query= Select * from MyDB where UserID==db.userID, return query.firstordefault`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why don't you have a class, UserDetails (or even just use AspNetUser class), that has Username, lockoutenabled and accessfailedcount as properties. Then load that up and return IEnum of that.

```
return from u in ManageEntity.AspNetUsers
    select new UserDetails{
        Username = u.UserName,
        Lockouts = u.LockoutEnabled,
        AccessFailedCounts = u.AccessFailedCount
    };
```

Answer (score 1):

You should to read some detail about EF.
I think you want to archive :

1. get a list from rows
2. best performance

I just demostrate a list as follow:

```
  var usernames = ManageEntity.AspNetUsers.AsQueryable().Select(m => m.UserName).ToList();
```

1. `ToList()` get a list.
2. `AsQueryable()` will not load all data from
   DB. so get better performance

.Hope it's useful for you.

Answer (score 0):

It would be better to have a class with all the properties you need:

```
public class UserDetail
{
    public String UserName {get; set;}
    public String LockoutEnabled {get; set;}
    public String AccessFailedCount {get; set;}
}
```

Then create a list of UserDetails like:

```
var list = (from u in ManageEntity.AspNetUsers
           select new UserDetail
              {
                 UserName = u.UserName,
                 LockoutEnabled = u.LockoutEnabled,
                 AccessFailedCounts = u.AccessFailedCount
              }).ToList();
```

Pardon any syntax issues, I'm far from my code Editor :)

Answer (score 0):

First of all: **use using**

```
     using (var c = ManageEntity())
         {
             // Your code
         }
```

I didn't get the idea of your `List<List<string>>`. If all data is connected you can create a class with all properties you need and populate it.

```
public class Data
{
 public string UserName {get; set;}
 public string Lockoutenabled {get; set;}
 public string AccessFailedCount {get; set;}
}
```

and add all data

```
public List<Data> FetchUserDetails()
    {
        using (var c = ManageEntity())
             {
                 return c.AspNetUsers.Select(m => new Data{
                                    UserName= m.UserName,
                                    LockoutEnabled=m.LockoutEnabled,
                                    AccessFailedCount=m.AccessFailedCount
                                   }).ToList()
             }

    }
```

Something like this :)

Answer (score 0):

I think you have confused most of us as to what you're trying to accomplish here.  The typical way to do what I think you're trying to do would be to have a function like

```
public class Manage
{
    private VatsWebEntitiesManage ManageEntity = new VatsWebEntitiesManage();

    public List<AspNetUser> Users { get; set; }

    public List<AspNetUser> FetchUserDetails()
    {
        var users = ManageEntity.AspNetUsers.ToList();
        return Users = users;
    }
}
```

although i'm not sure why you want the list to be a property of the class and also a function to return the list.. regardless.. Then you would just need to take the `List<AspNetUser>` and get the information you need..

If you need  a list of all user names.

```
var userList = FetchUserDetails();
var names = userList.Select(a => a.UserName).ToList();  //List<string>
var lockouts = userList.Select(a => a.Lockouts.ToString()).ToList();  //List<string>
```

If you want the first user or a user with a certain Id.

```
var user = userList.FirstOrDefault(a => a.UserId == userId);
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can create a class with properties of your table and 
get all required values from after join the all table but  foreign key relation is 
required.

example

```
class ABC()
{

public List<T1> t1 {get;set;};
public List<T1> t2 {get;set;};
public List<T1> t3 {get;set;};

}

List<ABC> lstABC = new List<ABC>();
          lstABC = (from A in db.T1
                    join B in db.T2  on A.ID equals B.ID                       
                    join C in db.T3 on B.ID equals C.ID                                                
                    select new ABC
                     {
                       t1=A,
                       t2=B,
                       t3 =C  

                     }).ToList();
```